# Can only retrieve 4 hours per day from openweathermap's 5 day forecast

Tags: c#, .net, openweathermap

I'm attempting to get all the hours for a particular day in order to display them in the grid, the problem seems to be that I only get 4 of the hours.  Here's the relevant code:

```html
public List<list> GetHourlyForecast(DateTime p_dt)
{
    List<list> retval;
    var objRetval = list.OrderBy(l => l.GetDate().Hour).Where(l => l.GetDate().Date == p_dt.Date);
    retval = objRetval.ToList();
    return retval;
}

public DateTime GetDate()
{
    /*
    DateTimeOffset dtOffset = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(long.Parse(dt.ToString()));
    DateTime retval = dtOffset.DateTime;
    return retval;
    */

    DateTime retval = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(dt);
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: Is there a restriction on their API? Maybe?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. The code does added does not seem to relate to the openweathermap api. Are you having issues with the api or with filtering of that data? If you are having issues with the api it may be useful to add the request and response data.

Comment: I'm retrieving the data just fine.  I think the problem is that I'm interpreting it wrong or comparing apples to oranges when I'm filtering based on the date.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable without a [mcve].